# Having issues getting around the scope of my event handler(ASPX .NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to template control panels in my site so I can take a panel and populate it fully. I'm good up until the point where my event handling needs to access functions on my page. My current test will take me to a login redirect page. So how can I get this event handler to perform a redirect?

```
public class DebugButton : Button
{
    public string msg;
    public DebugButton()
    {
        this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);
        this.ID = "txtdbgButton";
        this.Text = "Click me!";
        msg = "not set";
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msg = "Event handler clicked";
    }
}
```

****on the Page****

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
DebugButton btnDebug = new DebugButton();
PnlMain.Controls.Add(btnDebug);
```

Really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do a redirect you can use:

**Note:**
Assuming that your login page is named `login.aspx` and it is located in root folder of your website.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
}
```

or

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys I really appreciate it! The idea to what I wanted to do is create fully contained web controls that I could just reuse amongst all my pages. I prefer the N-Tier architecture, but time-wise I thought it would be nice for instance to have a custom panel class that automatically has everything in it and when you click the button it will initiate the appropriate behaviour. However the problem is when I want to redirect it, I have to create the event handler IN the actual login.cs that's a part of the aspx.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the event to have access to the page, then the page needs to subscribe to the click event.

Aka:

***on the Page***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DebugButton btnDebug = new DebugButton();
    btnDebug.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button1_Click);
    PnlMain.Controls.Add(btnDebug);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // access whatever you want on the page here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that that System.Web.HttpContext.Current will get me the current context of the page. So long as the custom class is part of the app(this one is in the apps folder of course) I'm good to go. Heres a sample of my quick TestTemplate that I used to make a custom button.

```
public class TestTemplate : Button
{
    public TestTemplate()
    {
        this.Text = "Click Me";
        this.ID = "btnClickMe";
        this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.EventHandler);
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("This is a test!");
    }
}
```